# make vfs linux cache more inclined to keep inodes over actual file contents

Tags: linux, cache, inode, vfs

I am using a centos 5 (2.6.18-194.el5).

I need to be able to list files very quickly, in order for my rsync backup to be efficient.

I don't really need to cache file contents, because file access response time isn't that important.

I've got hundred million files and they keep being added and removed, and I got the feeling that my inode cache gets replaced by file content cache, which I don't want.

After some lookup I think that maybe /proc/sys/vm/vfs_cache_pressure could be helpful, but I am not sure how to use it and how to check it actually works.

Dear vfs guru, thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one similar case I have a simple cronjob running every minute performing something like

```
find /some/mount/point 2&>1 >/dev/null
```

That way directory listing of 50 million files is forced to stay in cache.

Comment: So assuming my backup tool is rsync, and given that it internally does something like a find, I suppose I just need to backup as frequently as possible?

Comment: Maybe so. For me rsync every minute was not possible since it's more heavy operation than a simple find; I rsync couple of times a day but keep the directory cache hot with that cron job.